# Flexbox div not taking up entire horizontal space

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have an angular page with 3 components i'm trying to get to fill the entire horizontal space. Currently the parent flexbox div is not expanding to the full length, even though I have width: 100% on it. I am able to change the width using pixel values instead, however I have no idea how wide the viewport is going to be when the page is loaded. I have tried setting the margin and padding to 0, making sure the child flexdivs widths add up to 100%, etc...

Relevant html:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px" id="bottomContainer">
      <div fxFlex="1 0 40%"><mat-card gdArea="chart">
        <mat-card-subtitle>Messages Flagged <br>{{period}}<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon></button></mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="period = 'Week'; periodInt = 0; changeMessagesFlaggedChartPeriod('Week')">Week</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="period = 'Month'; periodInt = 1; changeMessagesFlaggedChartPeriod('Month')">Month</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="period = 'Year'; periodInt = 2; changeMessagesFlaggedChartPeriod('Year')">Year</button>
        </mat-menu>
        <mat-card-content gdAreas="chart | list" gdRows="auto">
          <div style="display: block">
            <canvas baseChart
                    [datasets]="this.currentMessagesFlaggedDataset"
                    [labels]="this.MESSAGES_FLAGGED_LABELS"
                    chartType="radar"
                    [options]="this.messagesFlaggedChartOptions"
                    [colors]="this.channelData.chartColors"
                    height="100%"
                    width="100%"
          ></canvas>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card></div>

      <div fxFlex="1 1 30%"><mat-card class="mat-elevation-z2 channelUserTableContainer">
        <mat-card-subtitle>Most Negative Users</mat-card-subtitle>
        <table mat-table class="channelUserTable" [dataSource]="channelData.negativeUsers">
          <!-- Username column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.username}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Number of flags column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="numFlags">
            <th mat-header-cell class="textAlignRight" *matHeaderCellDef>Number of Flags</th>
            <td mat-cell class="textAlignRight" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.numFlags}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="userTableColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: userTableColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
      </mat-card></div>

      <div fxFlex="1 1 30%"><mat-card class="mat-elevation-z2 channelUserTableContainer">
        <mat-card-subtitle>Most Positive Users</mat-card-subtitle>
        <table mat-table class="channelUserTable" [dataSource]="channelData.positiveUsers">
          <!-- Username column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.username}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Number of flags column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="numFlags">
            <th mat-header-cell class="textAlignRight" *matHeaderCellDef>Number of Flags</th>
            <td mat-cell class="textAlignRight" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.numFlags}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="userTableColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: userTableColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
      </mat-card></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

#channelHeaderText {
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mindChartNoMargin :nth-child(1) {
  margin: 0;
}

.channelUserTable {
  width: 100%;
}

.channelUserTableContainer {
  background-color: white;
}

.textAlignRight {
  text-align: right;
}

#bottomContainer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: the issue]

Help is much appreciated

Comment: change your 100% to 100vw and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the width to the container instead, also try making the container a flexbox and the items flex too.

```
.channelUserTableContainer { 
    background-color: white; 
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; 
}

.channelUserTable {
    display: flex;
}
```

I like to add a dotted line to understand how the flexboxes are working so you could also add a dotted border

`border: dotted;`